# How do I change the border color of empty fields and prevent a form from submitting?

Tags: html, jquery, css

```
<?php

require("../konekcija/konekcija.php");
require("../modeli/korisnik.php");

session_start();
if(isset($_POST["button"])) {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $lozinka = $_POST["lozinka"];

    $korisnik = new Korisnik(1, "", "", $email, $lozinka);
    $odgovor = Korisnik::prijava($email, $konekcija);
    $rez = $odgovor->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    $lozinka = $rez["lozinka"] ?? " ";
    $korisnikID = $rez["korisnikID"] ?? " ";
    $greska = 0;

    if (!password_verify($_POST["lozinka"], $lozinka)) {
        $greska = 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION["korisnik"] = $korisnikID;
        setcookie("korisnik", $korisnikID, time() + 60*60*60);
        header("Location: glavna.php");
        exit();
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Task Manager - Prijava</title>
    <link href="../style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contentreg">
        <div id = "logocontainer_reg">
            <a href="index.php" id="logolink"><img src="../slike/logo.svg" id="logo"></a>
        </div>

        <h2 id="crvena">Prijava</h2>
    
        <form class="container" method="post" action="" id="forma" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>      
            <h3>Email*</h3>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" required>        
            <h3>Lozinka*</h3>
            <input type="password" name="lozinka" id="lozinka" class="input" placeholder="Šifra" required>   
            
            <div id="nepoklapajuse">
                <h4 class="crvena">Email adresa i lozinka se ne poklapaju - pokušaj opet</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="buttoncontainer">
                <button class="button" name="button" id="button" type="submit">Prijavi se</button>
            </div>

            <a href="registracija.php" class="reroute"><p>Nemaš nalog? Registruj se<p></a>
        </form>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<script>  
    function promeniFormu() {
            $("#forma").on("submit", function(){
                if($("#email").val() != null){
                    $("#forma").submit();
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#email").css("border", "2px solid red");
                }
            })
        }
    promeniFormu();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to stop the form from submitting (and reloading the page) if the email field is empty and for its border to become red. With the way I've written my code the page keeps refreshing without doing anything of course, because the required field don't match to do a log-in. Can someone help me out with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$("#forma").on("submit", function(event){ event.preventDefault();` <- that will prevent form submit

Comment: You have turned off native browser validation with the `novalidate` attribute on the form, do you really need to do that?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've turned it off because I get the default pop-ups. I want to display my own messages with different lettering on the screen, that's why.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini How do I define what the event is with the code I have and/or that you've written out?

Comment: on "submit" so the parameter event will be submit event. you don't need to declare it.

Comment: I think I'd steer you towards the [form validation system](https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/eYPRoXM). This allows the browser to still use the native validation logic, but then you get to decide what to do. In your case, adjust styling (I'd recommend using a class instead of adjusting properties manually) and block the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a client side question, you don't need to post your sever side code...

All you need to do is prevent the default submit event, do your validations, then use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send the form data to the sever.

The `novalidate` property tells the browser not to validate on submit, but the browser still maintains the [validity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) property as the form is being filled out, so you can use that instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. There's even an [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) css pseudo-selector.

Also, I see that you're already doing it, but a good reminder: **never trust the client**, always validate server side.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevents submitting the form, which reloads the page by default
  
  if ($(this).find('input:invalid').length) {
    //code to notify user
  } else {
    //code to submit form
  }
});
```

```css
input:invalid{ border-color: #ee0000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="container" method="post" action="" id="forma" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>      
  <h3>Email*</h3>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" required>        
  <h3>Lozinka*</h3>
  <input type="password" name="lozinka" id="lozinka" class="input" placeholder="Šifra" required>   
            
  <div id="nepoklapajuse">
    <h4 class="crvena">Email adresa i lozinka se ne poklapaju - pokušaj opet</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="buttoncontainer">
    <button class="button" name="button" id="button" type="submit">Prijavi se</button>
  </div>
</form>
```